# how to set default language if language key is not found in cfbundlelocalizations

Tags: xamarin.ios, localization, info.plist

To get the native iOS Popups in different languages, I have added supported languages in info.plist as below

[info.plist contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lptz8.png)

With this, if I choose the languages French, English,Spanish, Italian or German. I am able to get the iOS native popups in the respective languages.
But If any other language is chosen, the language is dependent on "Preferred language order" in iPad Settings.

How should I default the language to English, if languages other than the above is selected?
For example, if I choose the language Portuguese, I need the default language to be English. i.e, the native popups should appear in English.
Thanks in advance.

I have also tried out adding the following

[Tried code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6yWH.png)

None of the above worked.

if I choose the language Portuguese(Not mentioned in the info.plist), I need the default language to be English. i.e, the native popups should appear in English.

Comment: Have you problem been solved?

Answer (score 0):

**Cause:**

It seems the iOS designed the language order. I tested the localization demo on my side and I get the conclusion below:

1. if I choose the languages I implemented in my project, I am able to get the respective language.
2. if I choose the language which i did't implemented in my project, `iOS` will choose the language in the `Preferred language order`, if he find the corresponding language in the `Preferred language order`, he will choose the language as you app's language. (**This caused your problem**)
3. If he can't find any corresponding language you implemented in your project, `iOS` will use the language you defined of `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` as default language.

**Solution:**

You can decide which language to use in your code. Get the `current language` of the phone and choose the `language` with the `current language` you get in your own logic.

```
 string[] languages = NSLocale.PreferredLanguages;

 // GET you current language in setting
 NSString language = new NSString(languages[0]);

 NSString esStr = new NSString("es");
 NSString jaStr = new NSString("ja");
 NSString frStr = new NSString("fr");

 //decide here which language to use
 if (language.HasPrefix(esStr))
 {
     //do in Spanish
 }
 else if (language.HasPrefix(jaStr))
 {
     //do in japanese
 }
 else if (language.HasPrefix(frStr))
 {
     //do in french
 }
 else {
     // SET your language to english here as default language
 }
```